# Magento 1.9 : Add Block to One step checkout

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, layout, blocks

I have a extension that shows a price slider for store credit in the Cart.

I do not use the Cart and customers go straight to the Checkout.

I want to show the slider on my checkout instead. Here is the code:

```
<checkout_cart_index>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/ei/creditpoint/creditpoint.slider.css</name><params/></action>
        <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/ei/creditpoint/creditpoint.slider.js</name><params/></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="checkout.cart">
        <block type="core/text_list" name="coupon.and.discount" as="coupon">
            <action method="insert">
                <block>checkout.cart.coupon</block>
            </action>
            <block type="creditpoint/creditpoint" name="creditpoints.cart.block" as ="creditpointblock" template="ei/creditpoint/checkout/cart/creditpoint_cart.phtml" before="checkout.cart.coupon"/>
        </block>
    </reference>
</checkout_cart_index>
```

My One Step Checkout XML file is using:

```
<onestepcheckout_index_index_flat_25columns>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addCss">
            <stylesheet>css/magestore/onestepcheckout/flat/onestepcheckout.css</stylesheet>
        </action>
        <block type="page/html_head" name="mobie_view" template="onestepcheckout/flat/head.phtml"/>
    </reference>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="onestepcheckout/onestepcheckout" name="onestepcheckout" template="onestepcheckout/flat/3columns.phtml">
            <block type="onestepcheckout/onestepcheckout" name="onestepcheckout_billing" as="onestepcheckout.billing" template="onestepcheckout/flat/onestepcheckout/billing.phtml" />
            <block type="onestepcheckout/onestepcheckout" name="onestepcheckout_shipping" as="onestepcheckout.shipping" template="onestepcheckout/flat/onestepcheckout/shipping.phtml" />
            <block type="checkout/onepage_shipping_method_available" name="onestepcheckout_shipping_method" as="onestepcheckout.shipping_method" template="onestepcheckout/flat/onestepcheckout/shipping_method.phtml"/>
            <block type="checkout/onepage_payment_methods" name="onestepcheckout_payment_method" as="onestepcheckout.payment_method" template="onestepcheckout/flat/onestepcheckout/payment_method.phtml">
                <action method="setMethodFormTemplate">
                    <method>purchaseorder</method>
                    <template>payment/form/purchaseorder.phtml</template>
                </action>
            </block>
            <block type="checkout/onepage_review" name="onestepcheckout.onestepcheckout.review" as="onestepcheckout.review" template="onestepcheckout/flat/onestepcheckout/review.phtml">
                <block type="checkout/agreements" name="onestepcheckout.onestepcheckout.agreements" as="agreements" template="checkout/onepage/agreements.phtml"/>
                <block type="checkout/onepage_review_info" name="review_info" as="info" template="onestepcheckout/flat/onestepcheckout/review/info.phtml">
                    <action method="addItemRender">
                        <type>default</type>
                        <block>checkout/cart_item_renderer</block>
                        <template>onestepcheckout/flat/onestepcheckout/review/item.phtml</template>
                    </action>
                    <action method="addItemRender">
                        <type>grouped</type>
                        <block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_grouped</block>
                        <template>onestepcheckout/flat/onestepcheckout/review/item.phtml</template>
                    </action>
                    <action method="addItemRender">
                        <type>configurable</type>
                        <block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_configurable</block>
                        <template>onestepcheckout/flat/onestepcheckout/review/item.phtml</template>
                    </action>
                    <action method="addItemRender">
                        <type>bundle</type>
                        <block>bundle/checkout_cart_item_renderer</block>
                        <template>onestepcheckout/flat/onestepcheckout/review/item.phtml</template>
                    </action>
                    <block type="checkout/cart_totals" name="checkout.onepage.review.info.totals" as="totals" template="onestepcheckout/flat/onestepcheckout/review/totals.phtml"/>
                </block>
            </block>
        </block>
    </reference>
    <reference name="before_body_end">
        <block type="core/template" template="onestepcheckout/flat/login_popup.phtml" name="login-popup" />
    </reference>
</onestepcheckout_index_index_flat_25columns>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<checkout_onepage_index>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/ei/creditpoint/creditpoint.slider.css</name><params/></action>
        <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/ei/creditpoint/creditpoint.slider.js</name><params/></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="checkout.onepage">
        <block type="core/text_list" name="coupon.and.discount" as="coupon">
            <action method="insert">
                <block>checkout.cart.coupon</block>
            </action>
            <block type="creditpoint/creditpoint" name="creditpoints.cart.block" as ="creditpointblock" template="ei/creditpoint/checkout/cart/creditpoint_cart.phtml" before="checkout.cart.coupon"/>
        </block>
    </reference>
</checkout_onepage_index>
```

This should add your block in checkout page. However, you will have to find the standard place for your block.

You may want to check `<checkout_onepage_index translate="label">` node in "layout/checkout.xml" file.

Comment: This doesn't work. Im not sure what to do. The one step checkout I use is a paid extension. Is there more information I can provide?

Comment: you need to find layout file for that extension and paste in your org qst.

Comment: Updated my question.

Comment: You can replace `<checkout_onepage_index>` and `</checkout_onepage_index>` with `<onestepcheckout_index_index_flat_25columns>` and `</onestepcheckout_index_index_flat_25columns>`. Also `<reference name="checkout.onepage">` with `<reference name="onestepcheckout">` and that should work. Remember, your module will depend upon this third party module that you have.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, here are the steps:

Step 1: make config.xml in your module **(app/code/local/Vendor/ModuleName/etc/config.xml)** with the following content:

```
<frontend>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <addextrablock>
                <file>addextrablock.xml</file>
            </addextrablock>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</frontend>
```

Step 2: Then create your layout file `app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/addextrablock.xml` with the following content:

```
<checkout_onepage_index>
    <reference name="checkout.onepage">
        <block type="vendorname_modulename/addextrablock" name="add.extra.block" as="add.extra.block" template="addextrablock/addextrablock.phtml" />
    </reference>
</checkout_onepage_index>
```

Step 3: Then create your template file **app/design/frontend/base/default/template/addextrablock/addextrablock.phtml** with the following content:

```
"Add Extra Block"
```